# Rotating the mouse wheel down or up using Advanced Scripting

Tags: naturallyspeaking

When writing a voice command using Advanced Scripting, how can I rotate the mouse wheel down or up?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate).

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/When-writing-a-voice-command-using-Advanced-Scripting-how-can-I-rotate-the-mouse-wheel-down-or-up